# How to prevent vanishing of shapes in SWT Scrollable Composite

Tags: swt

Im trying to create a little Telnet Client for a MUD. In this program i want to have a scrollable map. I already made this and it works pretty good. But as soon as i reach the borders it deletes the rectangles (painted with `GC`) outside the window. If i go back to them, the shapes are not there anymore.

Little Gif to show the problem:
https://gifyu.com/image/vhnq

Im scrolling with the the `ScrolledComposite.setOrigin(Point p)` function inside an async Runnable.

Canvas declaration + parents (room is an int with value 10):

```
    Composite container = new Composite(mapShell, SWT.FILL);
    container.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));

    scrolledComposite = new ScrolledComposite(container, SWT.BORDER | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);
    scrolledComposite.setVisible(true);
    scrolledComposite.setAlwaysShowScrollBars(false);
    scrolledComposite.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, true, 1, 4));

    int width = 10000, height = 10000;

    Canvas mapCanvas = new Canvas(scrolledComposite, SWT.NONE);
    mapCanvas.setBackground(mapShell.getDisplay().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_DARK_GRAY));
    mapCanvas.setSize(width, height);
    mapCanvas.setLocation(0, 0);

    final ScrollBar hBar = scrolledComposite.getHorizontalBar();
    final ScrollBar vBar = scrolledComposite.getVerticalBar();
    hBar.setIncrement(room * 2);
    vBar.setIncrement(room * 2);

    gc = new GC(mapCanvas);
    mapCanvas.setLayout(null);
    scrolledComposite.setContent(mapCanvas);
    scrolledComposite.setMinSize(new Point(300, 400));
```

Function to draw the rooms:

```
   public void changeCurrentRoom(Room newRoom) {
        mapShell.getDisplay().asyncExec(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                gc.setBackground(currentRoom.getColor());
                gc.fillRectangle(currentRoom.getRectangle());
                currentRoom = newRoom;
                gc.setBackground(ACTIVE_ROOM_COLOR);
                gc.fillRectangle(currentRoom.getRectangle());
            }
        });
        mapShell.getDisplay().asyncExec(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                scrolledComposite.setOrigin(getScrollPosition(currentRoom));
                roomText.setText(currentRoom.getName());
            }
        });     
    }
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You should only ever draw things in a `paint` listener, doing it anywhere else will not work reliably. Use the `redraw` methods to request all or part of the control be repainted.

Comment: can you give me a short example how to rewrite the `changeCurrentRoom` function?

Comment: No. You need to redesign the code to do all the drawing in a paint listener. Methods such as `changeCurrentRoom` should just update the description of what needs to be drawn and call `redraw` to get the paint listener called.

Comment: Also unless those methods are running in a different thread you don't need to use asyncExec.